# How to select passengers that flew with the same plane model?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the database description:

> Trip(trip_no, id_comp, plane, town_from, town_to, time_out, time_in)
>
> Passenger(ID_psg, name)
>
> Pass_in_trip(trip_no, date, ID_psg, place)

- Trip table has information about trips: trip number, company ID, plane type, departure city, arrival city, departure time, and arrival time.
- The passenger table has passenger's ID and passenger's name.
- Pass_in_trip table has information about the flights: trip number, departure date (day), passenger's ID and his place during the flight.

We should note that,

There can be passengers bearing the same last and first name (for example, Bruce Willis);
Here is the Question:

**Among the passengers who only flew by the planes of the same model, find names of those who arrived at the same town at least twice.**

I've managed to sort the planes that landed twice at the same airport...I think and I'm stuck at this point

```
SELECT plane
FROM trip 
group by plane
HAVING count(plane)=count(town_to)
       AND 
       count(plane) >=2
```

Comment: looks like homework ;)   Your query has count(plane) = count(town_to) and that is the equivalent as 1=1 (you will get the same results with SELECT plane FROM trip group by plane HAVING  AND count(plane) >=2)

Comment: Worth creating a SQL Fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that passengers have a unique ID_psg

```
select p.ID_psg, p.name, t.plane
from passenger p, Pass_in_trip pt, trip t
where p.ID_psg=pt.ID_psg
and pt.trip_no=t.trip_no 
group by p.ID_psg 
having count(t.plane)=1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be384/14

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name 
from
(SELECT trip.plane, trip.town_to, Passenger.ID_psg FROM trip 
INNER JOIN Pass_in_trip ON trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
INNER JOIN Passenger ON Pass_in_trip.ID_psg = Passenger.ID_psg
GROUP BY trip.plane, Passenger.ID_psg
HAVING count(trip.plane) >=2) a
inner join Passenger p on p.id_psg = a.ID_PSG
```

The plane and the town_to are in the subquery, so you can include the town_to and plane that they were on if you want.

As a teaching point:

```
SELECT plane
FROM trip 
group by plane
HAVING count(plane)=count(town_to)
   AND 
   count(plane) >=2
```

count(plane) -- this doesn't give a distinct count of plane by any means.  You could have count(1) or count(*) here just as easily.  Count is simply a count of rows, not anything to do with he contents of said rows. We can rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT plane
FROM trip 
group by plane
HAVING 1=1
   AND 
   count(*) >=2
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select p.*
from passengers p
where p.id_psg in (select pt.id_psg
                   from pass_in_trip pt join
                        trip t
                        on pt.trip_no = t.trip_no
                   group by pt.id_psg
                   having min(t.plane) = max(t.plane) and       -- one plane
                          count(*) > count(distinct t.town_to)  -- one place at least twice
                  );
```

The key to this query is the subquery with aggregation.  It is aggregating at the passenger level.  The first condition checks that there is only one plane.  An equivalent formulation would be `count(distinct t.plane)` = 1`.

The second is a bit trickier.  It counts the number of places a passenger has gone to and the number of trips.  If the number of trips is larger, then the passenger must've gone to one place at least twice.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help and explaining. Much appreciated. Worked like a charm